# Insert a FIELD TO A existing table with a condition

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL, I am trying to add a column to my table from another table with certain condition

I have `Employees2013` table that has `StaffNumber` column, and I have an `Employees` table that has `StaffNumber` and `Title` columns.

What I am trying to is create a new column called `Title` in `Employees2013` and select title from Employees where Employees2013.StaffNumber = Employees.StaffNumber.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
insert into Employees2013(Title)
   select e.Title
   from LandornetSQL.dbo.Employees e, Employees2013 f
   where e.StaffNumber = f.StaffNumber
```

I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StaffNumber', table 'xDevProjects.NA\OnderO.Employees2013'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: yeah, don't try to insert a `NULL` on a column that doesn't allows them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert only inserts records, if you want a new column, you must add the column to the table.

```
ALTER TABLE Employees2013 ADD Title VARCHAR(100)
```

Then you can update the table, setting the Title column

```
UPDATE Employees2013 SET Title = Employees.Title
FROM   Employees
WHERE  Employees.StaffNumber = Employees2013.StaffNumber;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I used incorrect syntax!